# PHP auto detect upload url path

Tags: php, path, relative-path, filepath

I work in responsivefilemanager and in config file I Have two line:

```
$upload_dir = '/user/uploads/files/'; // path from base_url to base of upload folder (with start and final /)
$current_path = '../../../../uploads/files/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
```

This wroked In `xammp` system (with sub folder. `/user/` is sub folder). if i move in real server i need to edit this two line and remove `sub folder` and one `../` from two line.

Now, I need to auto detect url path. My mean is : if i install in sub folder Or root folder this two line worked in my script without manual editing.

How do can i create this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular way to just autodetect what directory to upload to. The easiest is to solve this by just checking if the directory exists and use the other directory if it was not found.

However, I'd suggest having the same relative structure on both systems is the best solution. With the same relative structure this should work across all servers and systems without having to change anything.